# windows build tools installing error. How to rectify this error?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install vs_build_tools and I'm getting this error:

[image]

How do I resolve this problem ?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Wait for the update check to finish. Press the retry button

Comment: Pressing the retry button, after 1 minute again I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft servers might be over-burdened.

Wait at least 15 minutes before aborting the operation, then try again early in the
morning or late at night, before deciding that something is wrong on your computer.

If something seems wrong, ensure that you are using the latest .NET version
and that the Internet connection is working correctly and is not too slow.

If no explanation is found, download a
[Visual Studio offline installation](https://developerinsider.co/download-visual-studio-2017-web-installer-iso-community-professional-enterprise/)
and install using this version instead of the Web installation.

Comment: Could you please provide me the vs_BuildTools offline installing process steps.

Comment: This is described in the link. Basically, look in the table for your version, and see two columns: Web Installer and ISO. If your version has an ISO, click the "Download" link, download  the ISO, double-click to open as folder and execute the file `*setup.exe`. If it only has a Web Installer, download it and execute the command `your-download.exe --layout path\to\empty-folder --lang en-US`, and when finished, go to the folder and execute the setup, maybe named `vs_setup.exe`.